# Algorithm to remove elements that are behind Zeros (0)

Tags: javascript

I need to write an algorithm to remove numbers that are behind zeros.

I get 2 relevant pieces of information, first the number of numbers in the sequence. Then I get the actual sequence.

Exemple of data:

```
1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 6.
```

Every time I have a Zero I have to delete the number before it.

In this case, I have 2 zeros so I have to remove 5 and 4.

```
1, 3, 7, 0, 0, 6.
```

Now, I have 2 zeros so I have to remove 3 and 7. Leaving me with no other zeros.

```
1, 6
```

I am really lost in how to start.... Please help.

Comment: Refer to [***How Much Research is Expected of Stack Overflow Users?***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

Use a for loop and compare your i+1 value. If i+1 == 0, delete i and i+1

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through an array. Every time you find a `0`, splice the 0 and the number before it, and then continue from the last successful number.

```js
var inputArray = [1,2,2,0,3,4,5,5,5,0,0,6,7,8,9,9,0]
function removeZeroes(input){
  var count=0;
  for(var i=0; i<input.length;i++){
  console.log("i is "+input[i]);
    if(input[i]==0){
      if(i>=1){
        console.log("splicing "+input[i]+"and "+input[i-1]);
        input.splice(i-1,2);
        i=i-2;
      }
    }
  }
  return input;
}
var i =removeZeroes(inputArray);
console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through array and if you find value bigger than 0 just push it to answer array if you find zero then just pop last number from answer.

```js
const data = [
  [1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 6],
  [1, 3, 7, 0, 0, 6]
]

const removeBeforeZero = (input) => {
  let output = []
  for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
     if(input[i]){
        output.push(input[i])
     } else {
        output.pop()
     }
  }
  return output
}

data.forEach(test => {
  console.log(removeBeforeZero(test))
})
```

or modify input

```js
const data = [
  [1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 6],
  [1, 3, 7, 0, 0, 6]
]

const removeBeforeZero = (input) => {
   const temp = []
   input.forEach(num => num ? temp.push(num) : temp.pop())
   input.splice(temp.length)
   input.splice(0, input.length, ...temp)
   return input
}

data.forEach(test => {
  removeBeforeZero(test)
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is a good way to remove elements from an array. When you find a 0 as the next element, remove it and the next element, and make sure to back your iteration counter up.

```js
let arr = [1, 3, 5, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 6];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; ++i) {
  if (arr[i + 1] === 0) {
    arr.splice(i, 2);
    i = i - 2;
  }

  console.log(i, JSON.stringify(arr));
}
```